# what is the correct syntax for WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries in a MySQL table.  I've tried INSERT IGNORE but it doesn't seem to work.  I believe that this is because I have an auto increment column and thusly no two rows will ever be duplicates.

So, I am trying to use WHERE NOT EXISTS like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO testresults (ttime, resno, course, vid, playdate) VALUES (:ttime, :resno, :course, :vid, :playdate)
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempresults WHERE vid = :vid AND playdate = :playdate) LIMIT 1)";
```

but this returns

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
```

There are numerous examples on Stack Overflow but they all seem to want the inserted  values to come come from a SELECT statement; whereas I am inserting from programmatically generated values.

I think I just need a little tweak to the SQL stateent.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to have your `LIMIT 1 ` _inside_ the parenthesis associated with the `SELECT`?  And the remove the final closing (and unmatched) parenthesis.

Comment: Confused about your goal. You're combining the syntax for inserting one row with specified values with the syntax for copying multiple rows from another table. Which do you want to do here?

Comment: see this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: You don't/can't use `WHERE` with an `INSERT...VALUES(value_list)` query; but you can use it with an `INSERT...SELECT value_list WHERE ...` query.

Comment: To clarify.  I want to insert a row into a table but I want to make certain it is not a duplicate row.  The schema for the table includes the field uniq which is an auto increment field

Comment: `INSERT .. VALUES` allows neither `WHERE` nor `LIMIT`. Only `INSERT .. SELECT` allows these clauses. Read [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  INSERT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think `INSERT IGNORE` can work.

You said

> I believe that this is because I have an auto increment column and thusly no two rows will ever be duplicates.

That is true, but based on what it looks like you're attempting with the SQL in your question, a duplicate row for your purposes can be identified based on the `vid` and `playdate` columns.

You can add a unique constraint on those two columns.

```
ALTER TABLE testresults ADD UNIQUE unique_vid_playdate (vid, playdate)
```

Then `INSERT IGNORE` will do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I case you don't have a unique constraint then replace `VALUES` with this `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO testresults (ttime, resno, course, vid, playdate) 
SELECT :ttime, :resno, :course, :vid, :playdate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempresults WHERE vid = :vid AND playdate = :playdate)
```

There is no need for `LIMIT` since the statement will return max 1 row.